# Reconsider the "buffer" tag?

Tags: discussion, tags

> This tag is for questions about kernel buffer caches, including pipe buffers. These are used to store the recently accessed files and/or frequently accessed files.

Many questions use the [cache](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cache) tag instead, or sometimes in combination.  And the [buffer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/buffer) tag is "abused" for questions which are not about kernel buffer caches (and not about pipe buffers either - ?!).

I think this is to be expected.  The term *buffer cache* has become less widely used.  Modern Unixes implement [unified buffer cache](https://utcc.utoronto.ca/~cks/space/blog/unix/UnifiedBufferCache).  At least Linux developers seem to refer to the *page cache* instead.  One poster told me that an OS with a "unified buffer cache" has no buffer cache anymore, only a page cache :-).  (However cached IO is still often referred to as buffered IO).

I've checked my recent questions and made sure I'm using the [cache](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cache) tag.  And then it seems redundant to use the [buffer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/buffer) tag.

Should we do something about the [buffer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/buffer) tag - to make the tag description more consistent with how it is used - or the other way around - or to simply avoid using it?

(I don't think we need to start using a specific tag for "page-cache", though maybe you disagree :-)

Answer (score 3):

I think there is a fundamental difference between *buffer* and *cache*:

A **buffer** is to assemble smaller portions of data until a specific amount is reached; then the data is processed in some way. Like the write or read buffers `fread()` and `fwrite()` use in C. Or like in double-buffering when streaming data to a sound-card, maybe. Or the well-known line-buffer for keyboard input or line-printer output. Classical Ethernet cards had packet buffers, too; either in system RAM or dedicated on board.

Opposed to that, a (read) **cache** is some memory that is intended to be re-used often, meaning that the contents are read multiple times. So a *write cache* is actually a buffer IMHO. For example the result of a function can be cached.

Another difference IMHO is that *caches* are optional, while *buffers* are typically required.

And the **buffer cache** is a combination of both: Assembling (read) data in a block, and the reading that block buffer multiple times.

Finally historical mis-use of the terms isn't helpful in cleaning up the confusion.

Comment: Good point. Unix "buffer cache" is used to provide both buffering and caching. But there's a number of other important things that [buffer] might mean in our context, even if the term had not also become obsolete in the narrower context of Linux kernel development.

Comment: IMO the question is what does this site most need. 1) If [buffer] was removed from all Q's that are only about the [cache] features, would we find some use for the [buffer] tag? 2) Alternatively, if we wanted to label everything with a [buffer] tag that was relevant to the current tag description (maybe renaming it [kernel-cache]) - is that useful & realistically maintainable, when we already have tags like [cache], [kernel], [linux] etc. ?